# Recover macros from previous MacTeX distribution

Tags: macros, mac, texshop, directory

I recently upgraded my MacTex distribution from 2019 to 2020. I had lots of predefined macros created with the Macro Editor in TexShop that I can now no longer access.

**Does anyone know where Macro definitions for TexShop are stored?** If possible, I'd like to copy the older version to the new distribution.

**Edit:** @Herb Schulz: When I installed the new distribution, it created a folder for the old Tex Live distribution files, but the TeXShop folder merged with the old one, so the Macros were overwritten. Thanks for the quick response! I think I may have a backup copy somewhere, thanks for letting me know where to put it.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the original setup?

The macros file is stored in `~/Library/TeXShop/Macros`. You can open `~/Library/TeXShop` using the TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop Menu Command. Copy the original file to your new setup and restart TeXShop.